# What causes this "no such table exception"?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, entity-framework-core

I created a .net core console application project as follows. I think several months ago this can be run without error but now it does not work anymore with the following error.

[image]

## Code

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=MyDatabase.db");
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SchoolContext _schoolContext = new SchoolContext())
            {
                Student student = new Student() { Name = "Billy" };


                _schoolContext.Students.Add(student);


                int result = _schoolContext.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine($"There is(are) {result} student(s) added.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

What causes this error and how to solve it?

## Edit

For your reference, the database and table do exist as follows.

[image]

I am working on Visual Studio 2017 15.8.0 Preview 1.1.

Comment: Is there a password on the database?

Comment: Check if you have to specify `modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students")` to configure model builder entity to table;

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, specify the full path if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After wasting several hours, I found the solution.
Unlike `MyDatabase.db` generated by migration in the project root, `MyDatabase.db` generated by default in `$OutDir` does not have `Students` table.

To solve it, I have to apply the following configuration  on the root `MyDatabase.db`.

[image]

Probably this issue is caused by VS 2017 Preview.

Comment: Still seeing it in VS2019.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer It was really nice of you to share your solution. Like you I had also wasted several hours until I find your solution. I'm using `EF Core` with `.NET Standard 2.0` on `VS2019` where it works fine on `WPF` with `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy if newer` and `Build Action` set to `None`. But for `VSTO` add-in, I had to set `Build Action` to `Content`. And all that was because I saw your solution (thank you).

Comment: @user You mean you have the same issue on `VS2019`? If so, my comment above may help.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the table does not exist in the database you're connected to.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Although this does not gives a direct solution, this is the exact answer to the OP question. +1